# R loops with factor creation

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I want to check if there are less than 4 uniques in my variable, and it's true, I want to create a factor from it.

I created a function:

```
 checker <- function(x) {
  if (is.numeric(x) == TRUE) {

   if (length(unique(x)) < 5) {
       x <- factor(x)
   }

} else {
  break
}
  return(x)
}
```

But it still returns numeric vectors.

I suppose, for some reason

```
x <- factor(x)
```

doesn't work, when I tried:

```
checker <- function(x) {
    x <- factor(x)
    return(x)
}
```

The cycle returns numeric values

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function

```
checker <- function(x) {
   if (is.numeric(x) & length(unique(x)) < 5)
      factor(x)
   else x
}
```

and then apply it using `lapply`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, checker)
str(df)
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: Factor w/ 4 levels "1","2","3","4": 1 2 3 3 4 3
# $ b: int  1 2 3 4 5 6
```

---

Or as @akrun suggests an option with `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(~ is.numeric(.) && n_distinct(.) < 5, factor)
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3), b = 1:6)
```

Comment: Or an option with `dplyr` `df %>% mutate_if(~ is.numeric(.) && n_distinct(.) < 5, factor)`

Answer (score 0):

Try the function below:

```
checker <- function(x) ifelse(length(unique(x))< 5, return(factor(x)), return(x))
```